# north of $1.02 billion for a global haul of $1.77 billion

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I understand "north of $1.02 billion" means "over $1.02 billion," but I don't understand what it means when followed by "for a global haul of $1.77 billion." Why not simply say, "has earned north of $1.02 billion. The global haul is $1.77 billion"?

> Overseas, *No Way Home* has earned **north of $1.02 billion for a global haul of $1.77 billion** to rank as the No. 6 movie of all time, not adjusted for inflation.

https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/box-office-milestone-spider-man-225516370.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount $1.02 billion is from *overseas* (not domestic). Added to the domestic take, it adds up to $1.77 billion.